# error with makefile

Tags: c++, mingw, ogre3d, ogre

I want to compile my C++ files with mingw-g++ in command prompt. My C++ files have OGRE3D libraries also. How can I add these OGRE3D libaries in makefile.
For example after I compile my files in command prompt I get an error like this ; OgreEntity.h :No such file or directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To your g++, you should give options. Some useful options are:

- `-I/path/to/library/include` This tells the compiler to look for library
  headers in this folder also
- `-L/path/to/library/lib` This tells the compiler to look for library's lib file.
  For example, let's say it's called libBerzos.a
- `-lLibname` This tells the compiler to which library it should link. In the
  example above, you would write -lBarzos

For example, let's say I have written a library myself named [shSGL](https://github.com/ShabbyX/shSGL). I have the files in C:\shSGL

Then if I want to compile a file using it, I would compile it like this:

```
g++ -c -o file.o file.cpp -IC:/shSGL/include
```

and build the executable with

```
g++ -o exec file.o -LC:/shSGL/lib -lshSGL
```

See this [Makefile](https://github.com/ShabbyX/shSGL/blob/master/tests/test1/Makefile) for a real example.

If you want to learn more about g++ options, just search for `man g++` in google and the first site would be [this](http://linux.die.net/man/1/g++).

Comment: @shahbazcan you give an example with detail or any link